# Can we use a method on [checked] property of checkbox to set it to true/false

Tags: html, angular, typescript, checkbox, checked

I want to set the [checked] property of the checkbox on a method call, but when I do that, the method is called but it doesn't change the status of the checkbox

HTML

```
<div*ngFor="let vest_style of VEST_STYLE">
    <input type="checkbox" value="{{vest_style._id}}" (change)="onCheckboxChange($event,i)" 
    [checked]="isCheckedFromOrder(vest_style._id)">&nbsp;{{vest_style.name}}
</div>
```

TS

```
isCheckedFromOrder(id) {
    this.styles.value.forEach(style => {
      console.log(style === id)
      return style === id
    })
  }
```

Comment: are you changing the this.styles.value in the oncheckchange event handler?

Comment: can you add that code to the question?

Comment: Yes, I am populating this.styles which is a formarray, with the checked items through the event handler.

Comment: But here this.styles.value is prepopulated from the backend, just need to set the checked property  to true if the value from backend matches the id.

Comment: Maybe the style and id isn't triple equal, try just using the double equal '==' instead of '==='. Also, does the console.log has the correct bool as you would expect?

Comment: Tries double equal as well, but nothing different. Yes, its giving the correct bool value.

Comment: please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i know what the issue is. Instead of your code, use the following.

```
let checked = false;
this.style.value.forEach(style => {
if (style == id) checked = true;
});
return checked;
```